# Monitor the creation of new processes

Tags: linux, process, monitoring, proc, events

I want to get a notification whenever a new process is created.

I've tried to use inotify on `/proc`, but it didn't report any event even though a new directory appeared in `/proc`.

I could list the `/proc` directory in a loop and check if one more directory appeared, but I'm looking for a better solution.

Comment: WRT why inotify won't necessarily work on procfs or sysfs nodes: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/26377/5538 <- Substitute "procfs" for "sysfs" in the explanation.  They are the same in this context, namely, they don't *contain* information, they supply it when read.  So if you are just watching for a change in meta-information associated with the a node (which inotify does), there won't be one.

Comment: Is your program running as root? What do you want to do with the notifications?

Comment: No, it's not under root. My program just notify me if new process is created. I even don't know for what need root in /proc. There is not way to write ( even under root ) but read you can do from ordinary user. NOTE: root needs only in root's processes.