# Who is stealing my pids?

Tags: process, debugging

I noticed that my Debian Jessie system is using many pids, even when the system is (should be) largely idle. The following shows that more or less 270 pids are used per 10s, while the number of active processes stays more or less the same:

```
$ while :; do echo -n "$(ps | tail -n 1 | cut -d' ' -f1) "; ps aux | wc -l; sleep 10; done
15008 155
15280 155
15555 155
15800 155
16074 155
16343 155
16612 155
16881 155
17150 155
17418 155
17688 155
```

Even though system load isn't very high, I'd like to investigate this and fix it (if possible) before it becomes a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the load stay low and the process count stay pretty constant, that just means short lived processes are spawn during the ten second period. Twenty seven processes per second might not be a problem at all so there might be nothing to fix.

On the other hand, that might be a bogus daemon or something trying to launch a process that quickly fails and doing it again in an endless loop.

To find it out, I would recommend using one of the utilities also created by Solaris [dtrace execsnoop](http://www.brendangregg.com/DTrace/execsnoop) [author](http://www.brendangregg.com/), for example [that one](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brendangregg/perf-tools/master/execsnoop) using [ftrace](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/ftrace.txt) or [that other one](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/examples/lwtools/execsnoop-nd.stp) using [systemtap](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/).

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else, your shell script creates a process for each command such as `ps`, `cut`, `tail`, etc., in that loop.  You could only observe the systems with an application (one process...) which scanned the `/proc` filesystem looking for relevant changes.

Further reading:

- [How to continuously monitor process creation in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22695960/how-to-continuously-monitor-process-creation-in-linux)
- [Monitor all newly spawned processes on a Linux machine](https://serverfault.com/questions/205780/monitor-all-newly-spawned-processes-on-a-linux-machine)
- [Monitor the creation of new processes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177750/monitor-the-creation-of-new-processes)
- [Watching process creation on Linux hosts](http://prefetch.net/blog/index.php/2009/12/10/watching-process-creation-on-linux-hosts/)
- [Process/Thread Start Monitor](https://github.com/pturmel/startmon)
- [20 Command Line Tools for Linux Performance Monitoring](http://www.tecmint.com/command-line-tools-to-monitor-linux-performance/)

Comment: Well, yes, that shell script uses some resources as well -- but no 270 pids in every iteration, right? Do you have a specific program in mind to monitor `/proc`?

Comment: I think you'd have to write one.  `top` is a good place to start.

Comment: Top would likely miss most processes lasting a few milliseconds or even less.

Comment: I had in mind a developer as audience.  Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: No problem, you didn't waste my or anyone's time. Sorry if my comment suggested otherwise.